# web socket connection did not reconnect after network reconnect on android webview

Tags: angular, websocket, android-webview, paho, network-connection

I have implemented a paho mqtt in angular for real time data flow from AWS IOT topic. Data comes as expected in desktop browser and android webview. I also handled case when network disconnected and reconnected OR aws authentication token expired.

This all working on desktop browser where network disconnect stop the data updation while reconnect again sending data to page. But andoid webview unable to sending data to page after disconnect and reconnect of network.

This is angular code for mqtt connection.

```
initClient(requestUrl: string) {
    const clientId = String(Math.random()).replace('.', '');

    const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(requestUrl, clientId);

    const that = this;
    const connectOptions = {
        onSuccess: function () {
            console.log('connected');
            // subscribe to the topic
            client.subscribe('topicname', {});
        },
        useSSL: true,
        keepAliveInterval: 60 * 60,
        timeout: 10,
        mqttVersion: 4,
        onFailure: function (err: any) {
            that.isError = true;
            console.log(err);
            console.error('connect failed' + err);
        }
    };

    client.onConnectionLost = (responseObject: any) => {
        if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
            console.log(' onConnectionLost:' + responseObject.errorCode + ' -- ' + responseObject.errorMessage);
            that.authenticateAWS();
        }
    };

    client.connect(connectOptions);
    // this.locations = [];

    // let i = 0;
    // setInterval(() => this.processMessage({ "payloadString" : this.testdata(i++)}), 10000);
    client.onMessageArrived = (message) => {
        this.processMessage(message);
    };
  }
```

I am able to get following console errors on android logcat via webview apis.

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] " onConnectionLost:8 -- AMQJS0008I Socket closed.", source: http://PAGEURL/vendor.hash.bundle.js (1)
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "WebSocket connection to 'wss://IOTURL' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED", source: http://PAGEURL/main.hash.bundle.js (1)
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "[object Object]", source: http://PAGEURL/vendor.hash.bundle.js (1)
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "connect failed[object Object]", source: http://PAGEURL/vendor.hash.bundle.js (1)
```

After that data flow is halted in webview.

But desktop browsers get only following error after reconnection and data transfer continues.

```
onConnectionLost:8 -- AMQJS0008I Socket closed.
```

UPDATE : Desktop Firefox browser also failing to reconnect with following error.

```
The connection to wss://IOTURL was interrupted while the page was loading.
onConnectionLost:7 -- AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.
```

Comment: I am getting socket closed error as well. Any news on how to resolve it or caused the issue, please?

Comment: Please can you share how you solved this issue